# Cannot position input field exactly where I want it

Tags: html, css, margin

Could you possibly have a look at:

http://www.talbotgardenservices.com

The problem I have is that, in the footer, I am trying to put a "Callback" form. Customers put their number in the form, hit Send and their number is emailed to me.

The weird thing is that I can't get the input field to sit level with the submit button - it's like there's a 3px (approx.) margin at the top of it and, whatever I do, it sits a few pixels below the submit button.

I am using the Thesis theme for Wordpress and that particular piece of code is produced by the "Contact Form 7" plugin.

Any help would be GREATLY appreciated - it's driving me mad!!

Thanks for your time.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: I could post the snippet of code but I can't isolate the problem area, hence the link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your css to match this:

```
span.wpcf7-form-control-wrap {
 position: relative;
 top: -2px; <---- Add this in
}
```

Edit: This is found in `style.css` line 27 According to Chrome